# httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync never return

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm developping a universal app and I have a problem on Windows 8.1.1.

The code works well with Windows Phone 8.1 but does not works on Windows 8.1.1.
On Windows 8.1.1, the method httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync never return..

Here is my code :

```
    public async Task<StorageFile> DownloadAsync(String url)
    {
        String fileName = url.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
        StorageFile storageFile = await this.DoesFileExistAsync(fileName);

        try
        {
            if (storageFile == null)
            {
                if (InternetHelper.IsConnectedToInternet())
                {
                    String login = "login";
                    String password = "pass";
                    await this.ConnectAsync(login, password);

                    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = this._container;
                    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();
                    HttpStatusCode code = httpWebResponse.StatusCode;
                    if (code != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        return (null);
                    }
                    storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    using (Stream fs = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    using (Stream content = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        content.CopyTo(ms);
                        fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        ms.WriteTo(fs);
                    }
                    await this.DisconnectAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.NotifyError(e.Message, url, "-");
        }
        return (storageFile);
    }
```

The method that call the previous method is :

```
    private async void ExecuteShowFileCommand(String link)
    {
        StorageFile file = await WebSiteParser.Instance.DownloadAsync(link);
        if (file != null)
            await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: In your Windows 8.1.1 code, are you calling `Task.Wait` or `Task<T>.Result`?

Comment: No, as describe in my post I just call
StorageFile file = await WebSiteParser.Instance.DownloadAsync(link);

Comment: Why are you using `WebRequest`. You should use `HttpClient`. `ExecuteShowFileCommand` should return `Task`.

Comment: Changing WebRequest by Windows.Web.Http.WebClient works as expected on both plateform. Thanks a lot